# Detect if a pod uses local storage of any kind

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to safely evict pods from a node through REST API and to achieve it I should omit all pods that use local storage. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you tell us the reason why you want to do this? Then we might be able to help you find a solution.

Comment: I'm trying to mimic the behaviour of `kubectl drain <node_name>` but I need to do it by REST API. By default it leaves both daemonsets and pods which are bound to the local storage. On the system I use there is a deployment with local storage which is used by other components as the storage provider. It's purely for development purposes, nevertheless whenever I evict these pods other components using it hang and are not able to write to it anymore.

Comment: You can filter by the name of the PVC associated with the pods `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=json | jq -c '.items[] | {name: .metadata.name, namespace: .metadata.namespace, claimName: .spec |  select( has ("volumes") ).volumes[] | select( has ("persistentVolumeClaim") ).persistentVolumeClaim.claimName }'`. You can write a code that get a list of all pods and than you can filter only the ones that are in the PVC you want.